# django TypeError: required() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Tags: python, django

There are no errors in the code but when it runs it doesn't work.
I have a project with a similar code and it works perfectly.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pablo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/pablo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/pablo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: required() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

this is the code:
vews.py:

```
def profile_view(request, username):
  user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
  own_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
  if request.method == 'POST':
      if 'follow' in request.POST:
          own_profile.following.add(profile)
          profile.followers.add(own_profile)
      if 'unfollow' in request.POST:
          own_profile.following.remove(profile)
          profile.followers.remove(own_profile)

  posts = Post.objects.all()[:10]
  return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'profile': profile, 'own_profile': own_profile, 'posts': posts})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import login, logout, signup, edit_profile, profile_view

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout, name='logout'),
    path('signup/', signup, name='signup'),
    path('editprofile/', edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('<str:username>/', profile_view, name='profile'),
]
```

Comment: Is there not any more of that traceback? You're not using `required` anywhere in your code. Perhaps also show the models?

Comment: No, that is all the traceback. The models havent got required() either. I think the error is with the parameter but I dont know what is the problem :(

Comment: Adding the imports for views.py might help. The Django version, too. I'm grepping the Django 2.1 source for callables named `required(...)` and not getting anything; my first assumption was that you were using a `@login_required` decorator or something similar on that view, but we can't tell.

Comment: Thanks!!! The error was in the login_required decorator!!

Answer (score 0):

The traceback says it right:

```
TypeError: required() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

so the error lies in any function named `required()` like you already know (from the comments on your question).

Though,

I got a similar error too:

```
TypeError: user_profile_update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

And I found out that,
the keyword argument `'username'` came because I added `<str:username>` to path() in urlpatterns but didn't use that keyword argument `'username'` in the path's view - user_profile_update()

So this could be solved by either:

- changing the path() and removing `<str:username>`

OR

- adding the keyword argument "username" to the view.

```
def user_profile_update(request, username):
    ...
```